# Go error: "fmt.Println not used". What?

Tags: go

What the title said. I'm getting an error:

```
fmt.Println not used
```

The line mentioned is the last line of my source file. I'm not using the `fmt` package in that file, but I did recently.

This happens when I try to build the package or run tests.

EDIT:

If I `go clean myproject` the project I still get the same response.

I ran just `go clean` and now have:

```
# myproject
<epoch>: fmt.Println not used
```

EDIT for the benefit of Cat Plus Plus, here's a source file triggering the error:

types2.go

```
package mypackage

import (
)
```

to run:

```
go build mypackage
# mypackage
./types2.go:4: fmt.Println not used
```

Yes you read that right.

Comment: My crystal ball says it's because it's not Wednesday. (Hint: we need the code.)

Comment: I thought it might be a more general problem. I'm not going to paste the entire codebase here. The error has been reported (then not reported) in 3 separate files, none of which use the `fmt` package.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus - as it's not Wednesday I've included the contents of the source file in its entirety (I hesitate to say 'code'). This looks like a compiler error as I suspected.

Comment: <epoch> looks curious.  Do you have something called epoch?

Comment: No I don't! That's why I thought it might be a bug. It has also reported this error in 2 previous files in my package randomly. I have commented out all references to `fmt` and now it works. But I have a feeling that if I uncomment them this error will come back...

Comment: This looks a bit like this: http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=1474 I have checked, some files ended with `0x0a`, which I removed.  I am using go1.0.1 fwiw. Still not workign.

Comment: I found the answer. Kind of what the compiler said it was, kind of not. http://blog.afandian.com/2012/07/strange-error-in-go-fmt-println-not-used/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was that I had the expression `fmt.Println` in a file somewhere. The compiler told me that the error was occurring in incorrect file(s). More info in this blog post.

http://blog.afandian.com/2012/07/strange-error-in-go-fmt-println-not-used/

Comment: Can you file an issue at http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list?  If the compiler error message doesn't identify the file with the error, it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're not compiling what you think you're compiling.  What does your GOPATH look like?  Remember the go command just goes by GOPATH to find packages and doesn't care about your current directory.  Also, go build doesn't "run" or even install packages and Go clean isn't like make clean--it really does something else.

Comment: I have been running and testing this project for ages. It JUST stopped working.

Comment: When I say 'run' in this case, I mean run the tests.